# How to convert jpeg dataset folder into one HDF5 byte format (Python)? Or is there any better way to compress dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, hdf5

I want to store my dataset efficiently, individual files occupy too much space on the disk. Is converting it into one HDF5 file in byte format is a good way to solve the problem? If so how to do that? If not, what is the better way?

Comment: There are multple posts on this topic. Here are 2: 1) **Simple example**: [How do I process a large dataset of images in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66823010/10462884) and 2) **Detailed example**: [Convert a folder comprising jpeg images to hdf5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641176/10462884) See also: [What is the most efficient way to read an hdf5 file containing an image stored as a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182846)